# Relacionamento N:N em Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mvc

Possuo 3 tabelas em meu projeto que precisam ser relacionados: responsabilities, knowledges e knowledges_responsabilities, que resume :

Cada responsabilitie pode ter 1 ou mais Knowledges, e cada knowledge pertence a 1 ou mais responsabilitie.

A tabela knowledges_responsabilities vai conter os id das duas outras tabelas.

O relacionento no model eu já fiz, e buscar os registros de Knowledges no form de Responsabilities eu já consegui.

O que devo colocar no controller de Responsabilities para funcionar?

Comment: Para funcionar? Funcionar como assim? Ires buscar os dados de responsabilidades e knowledges?

Comment: @CesarMiguel , logicamente deveria ao selecionar quais knowledges , uma responsabilitie possui, ele criar na tabela intermediaria a relação entre eles. Não estou entendendo como salvar os id's na tabela intermediaria.

Comment: Isto mesmo. Falta de pesquisa minha no Stack! Obrigado @Andrey.